# Action Script 3. Check array if any element not Jumping, then jump

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I need to make items jumping. I have array with 6 elements (items). I need to make that they randomly jumped, but if any item jumping, other should stay.

I have code for jumping, on `EnterFrame` for 1 item it working normally - jumping non stop.

But here is problem that If I try to use this function once (for example as MouseEvent.CLICK), item decrease item's y by 15px. If I use this function 2nd time It decrease It's y by 15px again. So at all I need to launch this function 19 times to make full jump.

```
//whether or not the main guy is jumping
var mainJumping:Boolean = false;
//how quickly should the jump start off
var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 15;
//the current speed of the jump;
var jumpSpeed:Number = jumpSpeedLimit;

function updateItems(e:Event):void {

    var j:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*5);
                if(!mainJumping){
                    //then start jumping
                    mainJumping = true;
                    jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit*-1;
                    item1[j].y += jumpSpeed;
                 } else {
                    //then continue jumping if already in the air
                    if(jumpSpeed < 0){
                        jumpSpeed *= 1 - jumpSpeedLimit/75;
                        if(jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit/5){
                            jumpSpeed *= -1;
                        }
                    }
                    if(jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit){
                        jumpSpeed *= 1 + jumpSpeedLimit/50;
                    }
                    item1.y += jumpSpeed;
                    //if main hits the floor, then stop jumping
                    //of course, we'll change this once we create the level
                    if(item1[j].y <= 450){
                        mainJumping = false;
                        item1[j].y = 0;
                        }
                }
```

I've tried to make for loop to use function 19 times  `(var i = 0; i <19; i++){ ...` ,but after It  item not jumping at all. Have you any ideas how to make that I used function once I made full jump?

After I created `var j:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*5);` It working in bad case, because It starting to jump 2nd items, till 1st not completed jump.

Answer (score 0):

```
//whether or not the main guy is jumping
var mainJumping:Boolean = false;
//how quickly should the jump start off
var jumpSpeedLimit:int = 15;
//the current speed of the jump;
var jumpSpeed:Number = jumpSpeedLimit;

// we declare the variable that will hold the random number
var randomItem:Number;

// this function will select a random number and make the item corresponding
// to that number to jump. You call it once and it continues running.
function selectRandom():void
{
    randomItem = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateItems);
}

function updateItems(e:Event):void {


            if(!mainJumping){
                //then start jumping
                mainJumping = true;
                jumpSpeed = jumpSpeedLimit*-1;
                item1[randomItem].y += jumpSpeed;
             } else {
                //then continue jumping if already in the air
                if(jumpSpeed < 0){
                    jumpSpeed *= 1 - jumpSpeedLimit/75;
                    if(jumpSpeed > -jumpSpeedLimit/5){
                        jumpSpeed *= -1;
                    }
                }
                if(jumpSpeed > 0 && jumpSpeed <= jumpSpeedLimit){
                    jumpSpeed *= 1 + jumpSpeedLimit/50;
                }
                item1.y += jumpSpeed;
                //if main hits the floor, then stop jumping
                //of course, we'll change this once we create the level
                if(item1[randomItem].y <= 450){
                    mainJumping = false;
                    item1[randomItem].y = 0;
                    // after the item is finished jumping, we remove the listener
                    // and make it select another number. It is basically a loop.
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateItems);
                    selectRandom();
                    }
}
```

I just copy/pasted your code and made some modifications. I believe you missed some curly braces somewhere. That aside, the idea is to declare a variable outside of the `updateItems` method, so the number of the item doesn't randomly change every frame. Hope this solved your problem.